# What is the name of this style of locking system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

Does anyone know the name of this particular locking linear locking system linked below? The closest I could find is a linear ratchet locking mechanism based on how it works but I am not sure if this is the proper name. Thanks in advance!
https://www.pond5.com/stock-footage/item/168050349-locking-mechanism-car-lift-when-lifting-car-repair

Comment: Please post a screenshot and relevant details directly in the question by using the [edit] option. More people would see the details that way. If this is related to motor vehicle maintenance, there is a dedicated SE for that. Try deleting the question here and posting there if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Yes, that is the proper term. https://patents.google.com/patent/US6382358B1/en

Comment: ratchet and pawl